# SELECT DISTINCT from multiple columns

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

This is a bit of a complex query, but I have a database of snooker matches, and am trying to generate stats on who has played and won the most deciding frames (don't worry about the rules if you don't know the game).

Table:

```
ID player1  player2   bestOf     player1Score      player2Score
1   1           2          9          5                   0
2   2           1          9          5                   4
3   1           2          9          5                   4
4   2           1          9          4                   5
```

What I am trying to do is something like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS played, DISTINCT(player1,player2) AS playerID 
FROM matches 
WHERE (player1Score=BestOf / 2 + 0.5 AND player2Score=BestOf / 2 - 0.5) 
GROUP BY playerID
```

The above query doesn't work, as I believe DISTINCT doesn't support multiple columns. The result I'm looking for from the top table is:

```
playerID played  won
1           3      2
2           3      1
```

The top row in the table is not displayed, as it is not a final frame.

I have tried variations such as:

```
SELECT GROUP(player1,player2)
SELECT player1 + player2 AS playerID, select DISTINCT(playerID)
SELECT (player1 + player2) AS playerID GROUP BY playerID
```

and a good few others. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: You are likely looking for `CONCAT()`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: Hmm.. nasty design. Try to learn database normalization. Don't worry, it's not [regular expressions](http://twitter.com/#!/shanselman/status/190543146323685377), you can learn it quite easily :-)

Comment: How it is possible for player1 and player to play onlythree games. As per sample data, it looks they have played four games. Player1 won three games and player2 won 1 game.

Comment: @Romil I think the meaning of 'deciding frames' are games where the last match completely decided who would win the game. In the first game, that was not the case, but in the next 3, the last game decided the outcome of the match.

Comment: adi92 is correct, and CONCAT() does not seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: Perhaps I'm using CONCAT() wrongly, could someone please show a quick example? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually have your tables with me so my sql probably has lots of syntax errors. But hopefully I will be to get the general idea across. 
We can compute the list of deciding frame games where player1 won and union it with the list of deciding frame games where player2 won. As long as we rename the winner's column name to the same string ('player'), the union of these tables should yield a single table marking out the number of times each person won.

```
select player, count(*) as num_won from ((select player1 as player from matches where player1Score - player2Score = 1) union (select player2 as player from matches where player2Score - player1Score = 1));
```

This should give you a mapping from each player's id to the number of times they won.

Then consider

```
select player, count(*) as num_played from ((select player1 as player from matches where abs(player1Score - player2Score) = 1) union (select player2 as player from matches where abs(player2Score - player1Score) = 1));
```

The use of the abs function should help you discover the number of deciding frame games each player played. Now we combine these two tables to get your final answer

```
select players_table.player, players_table.num_played, winners_table.num_won from (select player, count(*) as num_won from ((select player1 as player from matches where player1Score - player2Score = 1) union (select player2 as player from matches where player2Score - player1Score = 1)) winners_table), (select player, count(*) as num_played from ((select player1 as player from matches where abs(player1Score - player2Score) = 1) union (select player2 as player from matches where abs(player2Score - player1Score) = 1)) players_table) where winners_table.player == players_table.player;
```

Comment: I've tried this one, but get a derived tables error, I might take a look at this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you copy-paste the error? Did you give aliases to all intermediate tables that were made?

Comment: I didn't, the eerror is "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias". I'm not familiar with aliases, I will Google around, find out how to work them and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. Its hard for me to create correct SQL statements w/o actually having your tables & some data in a mysql console. As the error message says, every intermediate table must get its own unique alias. Basically every subquery is an intermediate table. The approach I am suggesting involves a large number of nested subqueries. You need to give each one an alias. So take every set of parens with a select statement inside it & add a different letter of the alphabet to the right of it. No two letters must match & all statements no matter how nested they are must get a letter to the right of it.

Comment: Aha, I see what you mean now. I will try it over the weekend, thank you very much for your help adi92!

Answer (score 0):

```
create table temp_score
select playerid, count(*) as won 
FROM(
  Select   case  when player1score > player2score then  player1 else player2 end as playerid
    from score
    where
    (player2Score=Round(BestOf / 2 + 0.5,0) AND player1Score=round(BestOf / 2 - 0.5,0))
    or
    (player1Score=Round(BestOf / 2 + 0.5,0) AND player2Score=round(BestOf / 2 - 0.5,0))
) a
group by playerid

Select playerid,won, (Select SUM(won) from temp_score)  as TotalPlayed  from temp_score
```

Comment: I like the look of doing it in one query, however I have tested it in MySQL, replacing Score_Cte with my actual table name, and this gives error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'matches as (Select playerid,COUNT(*) as won from ( Select case when' at line 1"

Comment: This answer was related to MS Sql. For MySql, You can store the inner result in a table and then execute the second query on temp table to get final result.

Comment: MySQL has no CTE as far as I know.